# can we execute an add_action function without the do_action hook

Tags: wordpress, hook

tying to customize a plugin , I found a function executed using the `add_action()`. however I looked allover this plugin for the `do_action()` hook . I couldn't find it. so is it possible to execute the function in the `add_action()` without the hook?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately the actions are just callables, and could be invoked several ways. To find where the action is invoked, get a stack trace, and print it somewhere. Something like

```
function my_the_content_filter($content) {
  return '<pre>' . print_r(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS),true) . '</pre>' . $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

Except in your case the backtrace call would go into a modified copy of the plugin, and in its code for the existing action you want to know more about. Also, depending on your situation, you might need to print out to a file, or use WordPress's debug log instead of adding to the page content.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the `add_action()` is actually the function name being called.

like

`add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );`

can also be called by `echo woocommerce_template_single_title()`

If you write `do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary')`, you get all the function that is attached to that action.

like so

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 50 );
```

Will all be called by writing `do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question and have been investigating it for a couple hours. Turns out that certain actions are triggered automatically by the WordPress core based on the hook name. I'm sure this is all documented somewhere, but I'm just going to explain the specific example that I tracked down. It happens when a custom post type is defined.

Let's say I've got a custom post type named "MyPostType". If I add an action with this hook name:

```
save_post_MyPostType
```

then that action will be called by wp_includes/post.php when the post is updated. The statement in post.php is:

```
do_action( "save_post_{$post->post_type}", $post_id, $post, $update );
```

Thus no do_action() is required on my part; the add_action() is sufficient.

Here's what I was investigating:

```
add_action( 'save_post_sdm_downloads', array( $this, 'save_post_handler' ), 10, 3 );
```

The plugin defines a custom post type named "sdm_downloads", so save_post_handler() is called automatically whenever the post is saved.

Hope this helps anyone else who Googles it.